# Using ng-repeat inside uib-tooltip-html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, tooltip, uib

I want to show a list of items in the tooltip which will come from the collection.
 I want to display this as a tooltip:

```
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs doctype" ng-repeat="d in missDocs(vm.voyage) track by $index">{{d}}</h4>
```

I don't want to create new HTML page. Your views are appreciated!

Comment: I have an array of object to display.

Answer (score -1):

Create tooltips with CSS.

Click on the link below

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip